# Return JSON from angular service to component

Tags: angular, api, http, service

I'm trying to pass a JSON from my api service to any component without subscribing in the component it self.
What happens it that I get the data inner the .subscribe without any problem in the `api.service.ts` function
But when I'm trying to get that data outside of it returns something else

**Here is the code:**

`api.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

public getInfo(URL: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get( URL )
    .pipe(
      tap( (fetchJSON) => JSON.stringify(fetchJSON) )
    )
}

// I'm planning to create more functions like this one to get particular data:

public getParticularData(){
  let infoJSON;
  let URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  infoJSON = this.getInfo(URL)
  .subscribe(data =>{ console.log(data) });
  // the console.log(data) inside the .subscribe returns my Json data perfectly

  return infoJSON;
  //this returns: Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}

}

}
```

`home.component.ts`

```
*the rest of the imports are here don't worry*
import { ApiService } from '@api/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class homeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( private ApiService: ApiService){

 JSON = this.ApiService.getParticularData();
 console.log(JSON) // returns undefined

}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making two mistakes:

1. You are returning subsciption.
2. You are trying to access data synchronously but ajax is async.

As a simple solution, dont subscribe inside the service but in the component

```
public getParticularData(){
  let infoJSON;
  let URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  infoJSON = this.getInfo(URL)
  .map(data =>{ console.log(data) });
  // the console.log(data) inside the .subscribe returns my Json data perfectly

  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
      infoJSON.subscribe((data)=>resolve(data))
  })

}
```

**component:**

```
   async myMethod(){
    let data = await this.ApiService.getParticularData();
    console.log(data);
   }
```

Comment: Well, I already did that. But I'm trying to avoind subscribing in the component(s). Because I will have to subscribe in ALL the other components in which I will need the same data. Got it?

Comment: you can use async await...i edited my answer